# Angular filter by text depending on dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem whit my filter
I want filter using my input text and dropdown , I try explain my problem and 
I hope you can help me.. I want to search about my selection in my dropdown and my input text for example i want to search nota=20 
thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/
 angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="appangular.js"></script>
 <title>HOME</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Alumnos</h1>

 


<input type="text" ng-model="buscaralumno" >
     <select name="seleccion" id="seleccion" ng-model="parametro">
      <option id="Nota" value="Nota">Nota</option>
      <option id="Codigo" value="Codigo">Codigo</option>
     </select>
  <table ng-controller="datoscontroller">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>CODIGO</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Nota</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="Alumno in lsalumnos.ALUMNOS | filter:{Nota:buscaralumno}">

                <td>{{Alumno.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{Alumno.Codigo}}</td>
                <td>{{Alumno.Nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{Alumno.Apellido}}</td>
                <td>{{Alumno.Nota}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);

app.controller("datoscontroller",function($scope,$http){
   

  $scope.importar = function(){

   $http.get('Datos.json').success(function(Datos){
      
      $scope.lsalumnos = Datos;
      
   }
   );
  }
    $scope.importar();

}
);
```

```
{
"ALUMNOS":
[
    {
    "Id"        : "101",
    "Codigo"    : "1292920",
    "Nombre"    : "Marco ",
    "Apellido"  : "Lopez",
    "Nota"      : "20"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "102",
    "Codigo"    : "1293231",
    "Nombre"    : "Renzo",
    "Apellido"  : "Chumpitaz",
    "Nota"      : "20"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "103",
    "Codigo"    : "1029193",
    "Nombre"    : "Cristiano",
    "Apellido"  : "Ronaldo",
    "Nota"      : "19"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "104",
    "Codigo"    : "1231232",
    "Nombre"    : "Paolo",
    "Apellido"  : "Guerrero",
    "Nota"      : "15"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "105",
    "Codigo"    : "1111232",
    "Nombre"    : "Roberto",
    "Apellido"  : "Palacios",
    "Nota"      : "10"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "106",
    "Codigo"    : "1123255",
    "Nombre"    : "Adriano",
    "Apellido"  : "kaka",
    "Nota"      : "19"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "107",
    "Codigo"    : "1244232",
    "Nombre"    : "Manuel",
    "Apellido"  : "miranda",
    "Nota"      : "20"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "108",
    "Codigo"    : "10120201",
    "Nombre"    : "Tania ",
    "Apellido"  : "renlo",
    "Nota"      : "14"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "109",
    "Codigo"    : "1123920",
    "Nombre"    : "Mario ",
    "Apellido"  : "Lorez",
    "Nota"      : "14"
     },
     {
    "Id"        : "110",
    "Codigo"    : "13939239",
    "Nombre"    : "Luis ",
    "Apellido"  : "Perez",
    "Nota"      : "12"
     }
 ]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand that you want the dropdown to select which property to filter (Nota or Codigo), you will need to use a custom filtering function.

Something like:

```
$scope.parametroFilter = function(input){
    return (input[$scope.parametro].indexOf($scope.buscaralumno) != -1);
};
```

and use like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Alumno in lsalumnos.ALUMNOS | filter:parametroFilter">
```

Alternatively, you could use a function to return a dynamic filter object:

```
$scope.getParametroFilter = function(){
    var filter = {};
    filter[$scope.parametro] = $scope.buscaralumno;
    return filter;
};
```

and use like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Alumno in lsalumnos.ALUMNOS | filter:getParametroFilter()">
```